# What kind of architecture is good for my JavaScript software?

Tags: javascript, architecture

I am writing a software for a website where people can manage the website content. The interface is similar to Windows with all those windows floating around, click-able components, type-able text fields, etc. The admin interface is written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I'm wondering what kind of architecture should I apply to my admin system before it's too late (I've written some minor code so far).

For example, for the PHP back-end I'm using MVC, but what should I use for the client-side JavaScript admin system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were developing an GWT application, you would automatically have an architecture. For custom JS, with AJAX calls a two-tier architecture would be more than sufficient. However, I prefer going the event-driven way, where I have a layer full of listeners and another layer of  handlers.  I use closures for the most part and use custom page-ids. Works like a charm. I rarely separate the AJAX calls out, owing to the single-threaded aspect of JS.

P.S: I had to use the term layers for lack of better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an MVC on the browser too.
But it may be overkill.

The minimum you can do is to separate the HTML(view) and the JS(logic) code.
We use a javascript templating engine ([PURE](http://beebole.com/pure)) for our JS app, but there are plenty of other available on the web.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) are a good start.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. jQuery is a library / a framework. I'm talking about in an architectural manner.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). It's an MVC framework for front end JavaScript applications. Version 2 is jQuery based so you'll get the power of that fantastic library into the bargain